# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'Horarios.Dia'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo un sistema de citas en el cual quiero que si el admin acepta una solicitud de cita el horario correspondiente a esa solicitud cambie su estatus.

Adjunto código de mi función.

```
public function update($solicitud)
    {   
        $user_id=auth()->id();
        DB::table('Solicitudes')
        ->join('Eventos','Solicitudes.IdEvento','=','Eventos.id')
        ->where('Eventos.IdUsuario','=',$user_id)
        ->where('Solicitudes.id','=',$solicitud)
        ->update(['Status'=>'Aceptada']);

        DB::table('Horarios')
        ->join('Eventos', 'Horarios.IdEvento','=','Eventos.id')
        ->join('Solicitudes', 'Eventos.id', '=', 'Solicitudes.IdEvento')
        ->where('Solicitudes.id','=', $solicitud)
        ->where('Solicitudes.Status', '=', 'Aceptada')
        ->whereDate('Solicitudes.FechaSolicitada', 'Horarios.Dia')
        ->whereTime('Solicitudes.HoraSolicitada', '=', 'Horarios.Hora')
        ->update(['Horarios.Status'=>'Ocupado']);
        

        return redirect()->route('home2');
    }
```

Y les adjunto código de la migración:

```
Schema::create('Eventos',function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id()->unique();
        $table->string('NombreEvento');
        $table->text('Descripcion');
        $table->foreignId('IdUsuario');
        $table->foreign('IdUsuario')->references('id')->on('users');
    });

    Schema::create('Horarios', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->id()->unique();
        $table->date('Dia');
        $table->time('Hora');
        $table->string('Status');
        $table->foreignId('IdEvento');
        $table->foreign('IdEvento')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('Eventos')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });

    Schema::create('Solicitudes', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->id()->unique();
        $table->date('FechaEnvio');
        $table->date('FechaSolicitada');
        $table->time('HoraSolicitada');
        $table->string('NombreSolicitante');
        $table->string('ApellidoSolicitante');
        $table->bigInteger('NumeroTelefono');
        $table->string('Email');
        $table->string('Status');
        $table->foreignId('IdEvento');
        $table->foreign('IdEvento')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('Eventos')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Me gustaría pensar que el error puede ocasionarse a como tengo declarado el tipo de dato del campo *hora*. He probado el query en mysql y sí funciona como lo muestro en el primer código.

Comment: Pero no le estas pasando un string para comparar con el valor de la columna time? `whereTime('Solicitudes.HoraSolicitada', '=', 'Horarios.Hora')`. Para que las comillas?

Comment: Mmmm no es un string es la columna que es tipo time

Comment: Le puse las comillas porque quiero comparar esas 2 columnas, si en vez de whereTime pongo where y utilizo esa misma sintaxis sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: Para ese método `whereTime`, es el valor con el cual comparar el valor de la columna `'Solicitudes.HoraSolicitada'`. Para comparar el valor de dos columnas podes probar con `whereColumn` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, eso funcionó, por ahora jaja